# Program not executing full, stops in the middle

Tags: python, dictionary, service

```
from brisa.core.reactors import install_default_reactor

reactor = install_default_reactor()
print reactor

from brisa.core.threaded_call import run_async_function

from brisa.upnp.control_point.control_point import ControlPoint

from datetime import datetime

service = ('u', 'urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:SwitchPower:1')

binary_light_type = 'urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1'

def on_new_device(dev):

    print 'Got new device:', dev.udn

    print "Type 'list' to see the whole list"

    if not dev:
            return

def get_switch_service(device):

    return device.services[service[1]]

def create_control_point():

    c = ControlPoint()

    print "hello"   

    c.subscribe('new_device_event', on_new_device)  

    print "c"

    return c

def main():

    """ Main loop iteration receiving input commands.

    """

    print "hell"

    c = create_control_point()
    print "helllo"

    c.start()

    run_async_function(_handle_cmds, (c, ))

    reactor.add_after_stop_func(c.stop)

    reactor.main()

def _exit(c):

    """ Stops the _handle_cmds loop

    """

    global running_handle_cmds

    running_handle_cmds = False

def _search(c):

    """ Start searching for devices of type upnp:rootdevice and repeat

    search every 600 seconds (UPnP default)

    """

    c.start_search(600, 'upnp:rootdevice')


def _get_status(c):

    """ Gets the binary light status and print if it's on or off.

    """

    try:

        service = get_switch_service(c.current_server)

        status_response = service.GetStatus()

        if status_response['ResultStatus'] == '1':

            print 'Binary light status is on'

        else:

            print 'Binary light status is off'

    except Exception, e:

        if not hasattr(c, 'current_server') or not c.current_server:

            print 'BinaryLight device not set.Please use set_light <n>'

        else:

            print 'Error in get_status():', e

def _get_target(c):

    """ Gets the binary light target and print if it's on or off.

    """

    try:

        service = get_switch_service(c.current_server)

        status_response = service.GetTarget()

        if status_response['RetTargetValue'] == '1':

            print 'Binary light target is on'

        else:

            print 'Binary light target is off'

    except Exception, e:

        if not hasattr(c, 'current_server') or not c.current_server:

            print 'BinaryLight device not set.Please use set_light <n>'

        else:

            print 'Error in get_target():', e

def _stop(c):

    """ Stop searching

    """

    c.stop_search()

def _list_devices(c):

    """ Lists the devices that are in network.

    """

    k = 0

    for d in c.get_devices().values():

        print 'Device no.:', k

        print 'UDN:', d.udn

        print 'Name:', d.friendly_name

        print 'Device type:', d.device_type

        print 'Services:', d.services.keys() # Only print services name

        print

        k += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "hello"

    main()
```

I am getting the output:

ankit@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python controlpt.py

```
<brisa.core.reactors.glib2.GLib2Reactor object at 0x88c3e0c>
hello
hell
```

It is not going to the line c = create_control_point. why is that? please guide me in removing this error.

Comment: I recommend you print more helpful comments such as "Finished create_control_point" and "Inside create_control_point", rather than different variations on "Hello" with different numbers of ls.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this 'brisa' library. I would gather that, for some reason, the `ControlPoint` constructor is exiting the entire program using sys.exit() (or is calling some equivalent C code).

Run the program on the command-line, like this:

```
$ python
>>> import controlpt
>>> controlpt.main()
```

Then you should be able to see if it is actually quitting the whole process. If it dumps you back to the >>> prompt, then I don't know what's going on. But if it quits Python entirely, it means that that `ControlPoint` constructor is quitting.

Comment: yes...you right, the controlpoint constructor is quitting. How should I made it correct? You can see the Brisa library here:http://brisa.garage.maemo.org/apidoc/index.html..plz do advice me.

Comment: I had a brief look at those documents. Nothing obvious springs to mind, except that the ControlPoint constructor calls a *lot* of other constructors with a lot of code. Any of those could be causing it. I would look for calls to C code; that is probably more likely to be quitting (perhaps some C code is quitting on an error condition, rather than raising a proper Python exception).